# Returning a static value as a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, q

In NodeJS I am wrapping a promise function to return a static variable. I am sure there is a better way but I couldn't find it on Q's [docs](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference). This works however the Q.Promise seems redundant:

```
function parseXML(filepath) {
    return Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject, notify) {

       readXML(filepath).then(function (xml) {

        ... (long synchronised code)...

        //console.log('products -> ', products);
        resolve(products);

    }).catch(function (err) {
        reject(err);
    });
});
}
```

In Angular I would use $q.when but within the Q library "when" seems to have a different role, as I understand. I am surely missing some "when" method. This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
 function parseXML(filepath) {
    readXML(filepath).then(function (xml) {

        ...

        // some Q method to create a fulfilled promise
        Q.???(products);

    });

}
```

Comment: You need to `return readXML(filepath)` from `parseXML`. Once a function uses a promise, it becomes a promise (as long as you return a promise from within) and in your case `parseXML` would then become `thenable`

Comment: But do I have to create a Q.Promise like the first example or is there a way to return the "products" variable without wrapping the method with Q.Promise?

Comment: No. Once you go promise / async you cannot go sync. Attempting to will end in tears. I can flesh out your example in an answer if it's not clear.

Comment: sure, It could clarify things for me

Comment: I am not sure I am phrasing the question clearly - I know how to invoke parseXML as a promise, my question is how will the method consuming parseXML receive the products variable?

Comment: With a `.then(function(parseXMLResult){})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112006/discussion-between-guy-and-wainage).

Answer (score 1):

Both, in Angular and Node, this should be sufficient:

```
function parseXML(filepath) {
    return readXML(filepath).then(function(xml) {
        ... (long synchronised code)...
        return products
    });
}
```